# Hover function для меню

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, hover

Есть структура:

```js
$('li').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
}, function(){
  $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item">Текст 1
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Текст 2</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Текст 3</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
<ul>
```

Проблема: при наведении на `<li>` второго уровня, активным становится и `<li>` первого уровня.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы, батенька, наступили на очень большие грабли. Кроме шуток.
CSS наследование называется.
И универсального решения нет.
Но есть ньюансы.
К примеру использовать CSS псевдокласс :hover для выделения. Это будет 100% работать.

Comment: Вопрос в том, "а как должно быть?"
Ответ на него определит "как сделать"

Comment: Должен выделяться только один <li> - тот над которым находится курсор. Но курсор, по факту, находится на обоими <li> - вот в чем проблема